# How to transfer my files to R Projects, and then to GitHub?

Tags: r, github

I have 3 r scripts;

1. data1.r
2. data2.r
3. graph1.r

the two data files, run some math and generate 2 separate data files, which I save in my working directory. I then call these two files in *graph1.r* and use it to plot the data.

How can I organise and create an R project which has;

- these two data files - *data1.r* and *data2.r*
- another file which calls these files (*graph1.r*)
- Output of *graph1.r*

I would then like to share all of this on GitHub (I know how to do this part).

Edit -

Here is the data1 script

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = seq(1,100,1), y=rnorm(100))
save(df1, file = "data1.Rda")
```

Here is the data2 script

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = seq(1,100,1), y=rnorm(100))
save(df2, file = "data2.Rda")
```

Here is the graph1 script

```
load(file = "data1.Rda") 
load(file = "data2.Rda") 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+geom_point(data= df1, aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(data= df2, aes(x=x,y=y))
```

Question worded differently -

How would the above need to be executed inside a project?

I have looked at the following tutorials -

- https://r4ds.had.co.nz/workflow-projects.html
- [https://martinctc.github.io/blog/rstudio-projects-and-working-directories-a-beginner's-guide/](https://martinctc.github.io/blog/rstudio-projects-and-working-directories-a-beginner%27s-guide/)
- https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-gapminder/02-project-intro/
- https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/
- https://chrisvoncsefalvay.com/2018/08/09/structuring-r-projects/
- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the edits. Might you have a suggestion on how to link files within a project? Kind regards

Comment: If I did I would have posted it already. Editing takes no technology-specific knowledge, I don't know anything about R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have broken my answer into three parts:

- The question in your title
- The reworded question in your text
- What I, based on your comments, believe you are actually asking

#### How to transfer my files to R Projects, and then to GitHub?

From RStudio, just create a new project and move your files to this folder. You can then initialize this folder with git using `git init`.

#### How would [my included code] need to be executed inside a project?

You don't **need** to change anything in your example code. If you just place your files in a project folder they will run just fine.

An R project mainly takes care of the following for you:

- Working directory (it's always set to the project folder)
- File paths (all paths are relative to the project root folder)
- Settings (you can set project specific settings)

Further, many external packages are meant to work with projects, making many task easier for you. A project is also a very good starting point for sharing your code with Git.

#### What would be a good workflow for working with multiple scripts in an R project?

One common way of organizing multiple scripts is to make a new script calling the other scripts in order. Typically, I number the scripts so it's easy to see the order to call them. For example, here I would create `00_main.R` and include the code:

```r
source("01_data.R")
source("02_data.R")
source("03_graph.R")
```

> Note that I've renamed your scripts to make the order clear.

In your code, you do not need to save the data to pass it between the scripts. The above code would run just fine if you delete the `save()` and `load()` parts of your code. The objects created by the scripts would still be in your global environment, ready for the next script to use them.

If you **do** need to save your data, I would save it to a folder named `data/`. The output from your plot I would probably save to `outputs/` or `plots/`.

When you get used to working with R, the next step to organize your code is probably to create a package instead of using only a project.  You can find all the information you need in [this book](http://r-pkgs.org/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. But the question is mainly centered around how to link files within a project rather than steps to create a new project in r.

Comment: Ah, OK. I interpreted "how to transfer my files to R projects" as "how to create an R project" - since once your files are in the same folder as the `.Rproj` file they are in the same project. Would you mind elaborating on your question? Especially: what do you mean by "linking files within a project"?

Comment: sure. First of all, I edited the question to be as clear as possible. Currently, I have three scripts, with (graph1) calling the output of the first two scripts. These data are saved in the wd. What is the RProject way of doing what I am doing?

My current approach is immature, and I feel there must be a better way to accomplish what I am doing..

Comment: I have updated my answer based on how I understand your question. Please let me know if this was any more helpful, or if I'm still not understanding your question.

Comment: This is great - gives me all I need to play around a bit and figure out how to do it for my exact needs. Thanks a bunch!